# Why move-assignment is called?

Tags: c++, move

I have some class with copy and move assignment, but move seems to be wrong in my example and leads to unecpected behavior. Why is move called and how can I avoid this?
C1 is assigned to C2 and used afterwards, but move is called and C1 is empty then.

```
#include <iostream>

class CSomeClass
{
protected:
   size_t m_uiSize = 0u;

public:
   CSomeClass() {}

   ~CSomeClass() {}

   size_t size() const { return m_uiSize; }

   void resize( size_t p_uiNewSize ) { m_uiSize = p_uiNewSize; }

   /* This operator I was expected to be called in all cases. */
   CSomeClass& operator=( const CSomeClass& p_rzOther )
   {
      std::wcout << "Copy explicit" << std::endl;
      m_uiSize = p_rzOther.size();
      return *this;
   }

   CSomeClass& operator=( CSomeClass&& p_rzOther )
   {
      std::wcout << "Move explicit" << std::endl;
      m_uiSize = p_rzOther.size();
      p_rzOther.resize( 0u );
      return *this;
   }

#if 1
   template<typename M> CSomeClass& operator=( const M& p_rzOther )
   {
      std::wcout << "Copy UNDEF" << std::endl;
      m_uiSize = p_rzOther.size();
      return *this;
   }

   template<typename M> CSomeClass& operator=( M&& p_rzOther )
   {
      std::wcout << "Move UNDEF" << std::endl;
      p_rzOther.resize( 0u );
      return *this;
   }
#endif
};


int main()
{
   CSomeClass C1;
   CSomeClass C2;

   C1.resize( 1u );

   std::wcout << L"C1 size before: " << C2.size() << std::endl;

   C2 = C1;

   std::wcout << L"C1 size after: " << C2.size() << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

This results in the following output:

```
C1 size before: 1
Move UNDEF
C1 size after: 0
```

My real problem is a bit more complicated (with more templates and a large range of assignment variants).

If the `#if 1` is changed to `#if 0`, the correct copy assignment operator is called, but in my real code, there are cases where non of the assignment operators are called (instead there is done a plain copy which is wrong, too).

I hope you can explain the mechanism to me. What am I missing?

Comment: You accidentally made a forwarding reference.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Thanks, I'm not familiar with forwarding references so perhaps I should read about it. At the moment, I don't understand why this is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<typename M> CSomeClass& operator=( M&& p_rzOther )
```

Here, `M&& p_rzOther` is a [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references). You can pass both lvalues and rvalues to it, both `const` and non-`const`.

In your case, `M` gets deduced as `CSomeClass &`, which, due to the [reference collapsing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Reference_collapsing) turns the assignment operator into:

```
CSomeClass &operator=(CSomeClass &p_rzOther)
```

Because in `C2 = C1;`, `C1` is not `const`, the operator above is a better match than two other assignment operators that take a `const CSomeClass &`.

You can solve this with SFINAE, by preventing `M` from being `CSomeClass` (possibly cv-qualified, possibly a reference to one):

```
template <
    typename M,
    std::enable_if_t<
        !std::is_same_v<
            CSomeClass,
            std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<M>>
        >,
        decltype(nullptr)
    > = nullptr
>
CSomeClass &operator=(M &&p_rzOther)
```

And since this `operator=` can handle both value categories with and without `const`, you don't need the other one. I suggest removing

```
template<typename M> CSomeClass& operator=( const M& p_rzOther )
```

to prevent it from conflicting with the other operators.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now I understand the basics. I know how I have to change my code. I will discard the unused forwardings and replace them by some other methodes.

Answer (score 3):

`&&` in the context of an argument to a template function has a different meaning then in other situations.

It's called a [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) and it will be either an rvalue-reference or a non-const lvalue reference depending on what you pass in.

That means your `template operator=` is the best match for `C1 = C2` since both the copy assignements take `const&`, and `C1` is not `const`.